# Is it possible for multiple R Shiny Apps to be run through one R Studio environment?

Tags: r, shiny

I have a virtual machine running one R Studio Environment; is there any way for me to run multiple R Shiny apps using different ports?

Comment: Have you looked at Shiny Server?

Comment: In addition to running a `shiny-server`, which is my recommendation as well. You can run multiple R sessions, each hosting an app on a separate port. Your question really has nothing to do with Rstudio, the same logic applies though if you choose to initiate from the IDE, one app per session.